# How to change elements of array in Assembly(TASM)

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, x86-16, tasm

How to add 10 to each third element of the array, then multiply by 4. For example, we have an array:

```
2,5,1,3,7,4,6
(1+10)*4
(4+10)*4
```

Use macro.
I have to change the third elements that we calculate:

```
ChangeElements Macro
...
... 
endm
```

Please, help me or explain how to build a structure or loop.

Comment: Write some program generating your assembly code

Answer (score 1):

> explain how to build a structure or **loop**.

Before you could even start using a loop, you need to know where your array  will be in memory and what size its elements will have.
A common declaration for an array that holds **byte**-sized elements is:

```
MyArray db 2,5,1,3,7,4,6
```

A loop will iterate over these array elements. To do so, you first need to know how many elements there are, and setup a pointer to the start of the array. Then you read one element, process that element, move on to the next element, and repeat reading for as long as there are elements left.

```
  mov  cx, 7                ; Number of elements
  mov  bx, OFFSET MyArray   ; Address of first element
Again:
  mov  al, [bx]             ; Read one element

  ...                       ; Process that element

  inc  bx                   ; Move on to next element
  dec  cx
  jnz  Again                ; Repeat for all elements
```

### What is in 'Process that element' ?

Adding 10 is trivial, but multiplying by 4 should not be using an actual multiplication (`mul`) instruction, rather shift left (`shl`) the value twice.
Because the task asks you to *change* the array elements, the last thing you do in the 'process that element' step will be to write to the array with an instruction like `mov [bx], al`.

### How do you know it is the third element ?

For this you introduce a secondary downcounter that you initialize at **3**. Each time this special counter reaches **0**, you will have read 'a third element' and can start modifying the element, and re-initializing the special counter to **3**.

Tip: First write your whole program *without* this 'third element' requirement. Once that works and you understand *how* it works, you can insert the extra downcounter logic.

Comment: Or much more simply, `for(; ptr < endp ; p+=3)`, where `ptr` is `OFFSET MyArray`, and some other register hold `mov cx, OFFSET MyArray+7`.  Then you do `inc bx` / `cmp bx, cx` / `jb Again`.  Only if you also need to do something else to other elements would you actually want to increment your pointer by 1.   Using the pointer-increment as your loop control means you don't need to do any divide or modulo to calculate the loop trip-count before it starts, it just happens naturally.

Comment: @PeterCordes "Then you do `inc bx` /..." I think you meant `add bx, 3`. Your suggestion to use a step of 3 is what I would have used too, but in my answer I wanted to stay very close to the most basic visit-all-elements loop and build on that.

Comment: Oh yes, `add bx, 3`.  I don't see the benefit of making a complicated visit-all-elements loop.  It's way more code and steps to debug.  A visit-every-3rd loop is just as easy as a visit-all loop if you use an appropriate loop condition.  Pointing someone in that direction seems like poor advice when there's an easier way that only requires getting the termination condition right.